# Cut an Image into 9 pieces for Jigsaw Puzzle (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have to cut an image (600x600) to 9 pieces (200x200). I'm making a jigsaw puzzle with drag and drop. A lot of things are OK. Only left cutting 9 pieces and control. I read and watched many tutorials but nothing is working. Does anyone know how I can do it?

I have a 9 item scrollRect at right side. When an image cutting 9 pieces then will place the object.

I wrote this code at below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(img, new Rect(i * 200, j * 200, 200, 200), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
            Image image = list.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
            image.sprite = newSprite;
        }
    }
```

[My Puzzle Panel](https://i.hizliresim.com/OovO7z.png)

Comment: Instead of watching many tutorials you should have done one(!) simple search with a search engine of your choice: "Cut an Image into 9 pieces c# site: stackoverflow.com"

Comment: I could not only place the pieces to piece objects Image Component

Comment: did you get solution?